# Change a value in a nested array matching Id in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I have a nested array object which is like:

```js
const nestedArray = [
    { name : 'Living room',
      item : 
        [
            {
                id: "bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba",
                title: "Light",
                titleStatus: 'Home Daytime',
                image: Images.light,
                imageDark: Images.lightDark,
                selected: false
            },
            {
                id: "3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63",
                title: "Climate",
                titleStatus: '17',
                image: Images.meter,
                imageDark: Images.meterDark,
                selected: false
            },
            {
                id: "58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72",
                title: "Ventilation",
                titleStatus: 'Auto',
                image: Images.ventilation,
                imageDark: Images.ventilationDark,
                selected: false
            }
        ]
        
    },
    { name: 'Kitchen',
      item :
        [
            {
                id: "bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53cbb28ba",
                title: "Light",
                titleStatus: 'Home Daytime',
                image: Images.light,
                imageDark: Images.lightDark,
                selected: false
            },
            {
                id: "3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-cdbd91aa97f63",
                title: "Climate",
                titleStatus: '17',
                image: Images.meter,
                imageDark: Images.meterDark,
                selected: false
            },
            {
                id: "58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145vdf571e29d72",
                title: "Ventilation",
                titleStatus: 'Auto',
                image: Images.ventilation,
                imageDark: Images.ventilationDark,
                selected: false
            }
        ]
        
    },
    { name : 'Master bedroom',
      item  : 
        [
            {
                id: "bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad5xx3abb28ba",
                title: "Light",
                titleStatus: 'Home Daytime',
                image: Images.light,
                imageDark: Images.lightDark,
                selected: false
            },
            {
                id: "3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbdss91aa97f63",
                title: "Climate",
                titleStatus: '17',
                image: Images.meter,
                imageDark: Images.meterDark,
                selected: false
            },
            {
                id: "58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571eaa29d72",
                title: "Ventilation",
                titleStatus: 'Auto',
                image: Images.ventilation,
                imageDark: Images.ventilationDark,
                selected: false
            }
        ]
        
    },
    { name : 'Kids bedroom',
      item  : 
        [
            {
                id: "bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abbkk28ba",
                title: "Light",
                titleStatus: 'Home Daytime',
                image: Images.light,
                imageDark: Images.lightDark,
                selected: false
            },
            {
                id: "3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91kkaa97f63",
                title: "Climate",
                titleStatus: '17',
                image: Images.meter,
                imageDark: Images.meterDark,
                selected: false
            },
            {
                id: "58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-14557331e29d72",
                title: "Ventilation",
                titleStatus: 'Auto',
                image: Images.ventilation,
                imageDark: Images.ventilationDark,
                selected: false
            }
        ]
        
    },

];
```

Now i will pass an Id in a function and need to match the Id from the array and change the value of `selected` to `true` or `false`. Here's what i have done so far:

```js
    const onPressHandler = (id) => {
        let updateBool = nestedArray.map((x) =>{
           x.item.id === id ? { ...x, selected: !selected } : x
        })
    }
```

but it doesn't change anything from the original array. What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're only making a small change it seems a little redundant to create a new array for `nestedArray` and new arrays for each `item`.

Just loop over the data and change that one `selected` where the `id` matches, and then you can just break out of the loop - job done. That would be much faster because `find` *also* short-circuits its own iteration if it finds a match.

If you didn't want to mutate the original array just make a copy of it in the function, change and return that instead. Still a lot more performant.

```js
const nestedArray=[{name:"Living room",item:[{id:"bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba",title:"Light",titleStatus:"Home Daytime",selected:!1},{id:"3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63",title:"Climate",titleStatus:"17",selected:!1},{id:"58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72",title:"Ventilation",titleStatus:"Auto",selected:!1}]},{name:"Kitchen",item:[{id:"bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53cbb28ba",title:"Light",titleStatus:"Home Daytime",selected:!1},{id:"3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-cdbd91aa97f63",title:"Climate",titleStatus:"17",selected:!1},{id:"58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145vdf571e29d72",title:"Ventilation",titleStatus:"Auto",selected:!1}]},{name:"Master bedroom",item:[{id:"bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad5xx3abb28ba",title:"Light",titleStatus:"Home Daytime",selected:!1},{id:"3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbdss91aa97f63",title:"Climate",titleStatus:"17",selected:!1},{id:"58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571eaa29d72",title:"Ventilation",titleStatus:"Auto",selected:!1}]},{name:"Kids bedroom",item:[{id:"bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abbkk28ba",title:"Light",titleStatus:"Home Daytime",selected:!1},{id:"3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91kkaa97f63",title:"Climate",titleStatus:"17",selected:!1},{id:"58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-14557331e29d72",title:"Ventilation",titleStatus:"Auto",selected:!1}]}];

function changeSelected(id) {
  for (const { item } of nestedArray) {
    const found = item.find(obj => obj.id === id);
    if (found) {
      found.selected = !found.selected;
      break;
    }
  }
}

changeSelected('bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abbkk28ba');

console.log(nestedArray);
```

Comment: It doesn't change the selected value @Andy

Comment: Run the snippet and check again. I can assure you it does. @TanmoySarker. It's the first item of the "Kid's bedroom" object.

Comment: yaah my bad, it does. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You need to nest the `map` method to the `item` list, also `selected: !selected` will give an error, you need to set `selected: !i.selected` as `i` is the item.

```js
const nestedArray = [
    { name : 'Living room',
      item : 
        [
            {
                id: "bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba",
                title: "Light",
                titleStatus: 'Home Daytime',
                selected: false
            },
            {
                id: "3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63",
                title: "Climate",
                titleStatus: '17',
                selected: false
            },
            {
                id: "58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72",
                title: "Ventilation",
                titleStatus: 'Auto',
                selected: false
            }
        ]
        
    },
    { name: 'Kitchen',
      item :
        [
            {
                id: "bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53cbb28ba",
                title: "Light",
                titleStatus: 'Home Daytime',
                selected: false
            },
            {
                id: "3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-cdbd91aa97f63",
                title: "Climate",
                titleStatus: '17',
                selected: false
            },
            {
                id: "58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145vdf571e29d72",
                title: "Ventilation",
                titleStatus: 'Auto',
                selected: false
            }
        ]
        
    },
    { name : 'Master bedroom',
      item  : 
        [
            {
                id: "bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad5xx3abb28ba",
                title: "Light",
                titleStatus: 'Home Daytime',
                selected: false
            },
            {
                id: "3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbdss91aa97f63",
                title: "Climate",
                titleStatus: '17',
                selected: false
            },
            {
                id: "58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571eaa29d72",
                title: "Ventilation",
                titleStatus: 'Auto',
                selected: false
            }
        ]
        
    },
    { name : 'Kids bedroom',
      item  : 
        [
            {
                id: "bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abbkk28ba",
                title: "Light",
                titleStatus: 'Home Daytime',
                selected: false
            },
            {
                id: "3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91kkaa97f63",
                title: "Climate",
                titleStatus: '17',
                selected: false
            },
            {
                id: "58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-14557331e29d72",
                title: "Ventilation",
                titleStatus: 'Auto',
                selected: false
            }
        ]
        
    },

];


const onPressHandler = (id) => {
        let updateBool = nestedArray.map((x) =>{
           return x.item.map(i => {
             return i.id === id ? { ...i, selected: !i.selected } : i
           })
        })
        
        return updateBool
    }
    
console.log(onPressHandler("58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-14557331e29d72"))
```

Answer (score 0):

I definied `Image` as `{}` to prevent error as I don't have the entier code :

```js
const Images = {};

const nestedArray = [
    { name : 'Living room',
      item : 
        [
            {
                id: "bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abb28ba",
                title: "Light",
                titleStatus: 'Home Daytime',
                image: Images.light,
                imageDark: Images.lightDark,
                selected: false
            },
            {
                id: "3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91aa97f63",
                title: "Climate",
                titleStatus: '17',
                image: Images.meter,
                imageDark: Images.meterDark,
                selected: false
            },
            {
                id: "58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571e29d72",
                title: "Ventilation",
                titleStatus: 'Auto',
                image: Images.ventilation,
                imageDark: Images.ventilationDark,
                selected: false
            }
        ]
        
    },
    { name: 'Kitchen',
      item :
        [
            {
                id: "bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53cbb28ba",
                title: "Light",
                titleStatus: 'Home Daytime',
                image: Images.light,
                imageDark: Images.lightDark,
                selected: false
            },
            {
                id: "3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-cdbd91aa97f63",
                title: "Climate",
                titleStatus: '17',
                image: Images.meter,
                imageDark: Images.meterDark,
                selected: false
            },
            {
                id: "58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145vdf571e29d72",
                title: "Ventilation",
                titleStatus: 'Auto',
                image: Images.ventilation,
                imageDark: Images.ventilationDark,
                selected: false
            }
        ]
        
    },
    { name : 'Master bedroom',
      item  : 
        [
            {
                id: "bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad5xx3abb28ba",
                title: "Light",
                titleStatus: 'Home Daytime',
                image: Images.light,
                imageDark: Images.lightDark,
                selected: false
            },
            {
                id: "3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbdss91aa97f63",
                title: "Climate",
                titleStatus: '17',
                image: Images.meter,
                imageDark: Images.meterDark,
                selected: false
            },
            {
                id: "58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-145571eaa29d72",
                title: "Ventilation",
                titleStatus: 'Auto',
                image: Images.ventilation,
                imageDark: Images.ventilationDark,
                selected: false
            }
        ]
        
    },
    { name : 'Kids bedroom',
      item  : 
        [
            {
                id: "bd7acbea-c1b1-46c2-aed5-3ad53abbkk28ba",
                title: "Light",
                titleStatus: 'Home Daytime',
                image: Images.light,
                imageDark: Images.lightDark,
                selected: false
            },
            {
                id: "3ac68afc-c605-48d3-a4f8-fbd91kkaa97f63",
                title: "Climate",
                titleStatus: '17',
                image: Images.meter,
                imageDark: Images.meterDark,
                selected: false
            },
            {
                id: "58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-14557331e29d72",
                title: "Ventilation",
                titleStatus: 'Auto',
                image: Images.ventilation,
                imageDark: Images.ventilationDark,
                selected: false
            }
        ]
        
    },

];

const onPressHandler = (id) => {
    return nestedArray.map(x => 
        ({...x, item: x.item.map(item => 
            item.id === id ? {...item, selected: !item.selected} : item)
        }) 
    );
};

const id = "58694a0f-3da1-471f-bd96-14557331e29d72";
let result = onPressHandler(id);
console.log(result);
```