# change property using map but for nested array of object

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

I have above array of object within an array of object like below

```
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "id": "1a",
                "isChecked": false
            },
            {
                "id": "2b",
                "isChecked": false
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "data": [
            {
                "id": "2a",
                "isChecked": false
            },
            {
                "id": "2b",
                "isChecked": false
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

How can I make `arr[1].data[0].id['2a']` check property to true?

I know it's possible to use multiple map if I've index and 2a but I don't, what if I only have single "2a" as id?

Comment: just do `for` loop, search your ID, when found, break loop + return result

Comment: [Solution that doesn't use `map`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73107301/1377002) that I answered earlier today. Simple loop, `find` the object that matches the id, change the prop. Then `break`.

Comment: Why would you need the index? Just map *all* the inner arrays. Or if I'm missing something, please [edit] your question to include the code you'd use if you knew the index as well.

Comment: @Bergi how to know which parent to go to?

Comment: @JennyLe Like I said, if you don't know it, you go to *all* of them. Just no extra condition in the `map` callback.

Comment: Are you asking about changing (mutating) the object, or do you want to keep it immutable and return a copy of the array in which one copy of the objects has a new `isChecked` value?